# Changing/setting the path or route to the hub in SignalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I have a signalR application and it is working as expected.
But I would like to change the path to the hub.

currently it is /signalr/hub/ but I want to be able to set it to something else.

How can I change the route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the server you can do :

> app.MapSignalR("/newHubLocation", new HubConfiguration());